# How to add redirection rule and rewrite rule in Azure for xcart application hosted in azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I am deploying a XCart application into azure . I have various rules for http rewriting and redirecting written in HttpAccess file for xcart. Now I have deployed that application to azure and is running good .
Now I want to add all those rules in azure which is not taking from httpaccess.
Is it that I need to write web.config file for this rule which will take from there.
Or is there any other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at IIS url rewrite module for redirection and rewrite. See [here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite). This tool basically writes the rules to web.config file.

**Update**:What you can do is, on a machine with IIS installed, install this module. Then run this tool locally and create rules using this tool. This tool will write the changes to web.config file of the app on which you try to run this tool. See this [example](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

Google and you may find some migration tool.

Comment: actually I am using azure dashboard so don't have IIS direct access

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it correctly. Let me update the answer.

Comment: You can also do this manually by directly editing the web.config file, but that would require you to understand the xml format.